# ios driver lock device not implemented

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-ios

I have below snippet of code in my framework to lock the device

```
public void lockScreen() {
        try {
            if (Driver instanceof AndroidDriver) {
                ((AndroidDriver) Driver).lockDevice();
            } else {
                int time = this.getInt(Data, 5);
                ((IOSDriver) Driver).lockDevice(Duration.ofSeconds(time));
            }
            System.out.println("Screen locked");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Basic.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

I am using Java client 7.0.0, through Appium server trying to lock the IOS device (iPad). Getting an error from selenium. The method is not implemented , but the same is working fine for an Android device. Please suggest workaround or solution to resolve the issue.

Below are the exception stack trace

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'AMP00006', ip: '192.168.43.71', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '9.0.4'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver
Capabilities {automationName: XCUITest, browserName: , bundleId: com.apple.mobilecal, databaseEnabled: false, derivedDataPath: /Users/spritz/PreBuiltWDA, deviceName: Spritz's iPad, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: false, noReset: true, platform: ANY, platformName: iOS, takesScreenshot: true, udid: e9f0b277fbecf1bca7cda4b8e3d..., usePrebuiltWDA: true, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: 0769d1ee-f9d9-471f-a6d5-cb3642c86867
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor32.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is clearly mentioned in the Appium [documentation](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/interactions/lock/) that this feature is not supported for iOS or Mac platforms.

[image: lock device feature is not supported for iOS or Mac platforms by Appium]

**Reference link:**
http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/interactions/lock/

**Support thread (Appium):**
https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-lock-and-unlock-iphone-real-device-using-appium/15632/4